# How to exit a blocking connect() call in Windows?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock

Is there a way I can exit a blocking `connect()` call in Windows?

Note that I do not want to switch to non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Not an answer as I don't have the reference here but I vaguely remember that it's just not possible.

Comment: Maybe `CancelIoEx` does what you need? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: why not use [ConnectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: You can either close the socket from a separate thread, or do the connect in non-blocking mode and then switch back to blocking mode once it succeeds, and use `select()` to poll for completion. Or just wait for the connect timeout, which is about a minute.

Comment: @EJP In Windows, you cannot call `closesocket()` concurrently with another Winsock call (this is from the `closesocket()` documentation: *A Winsock client must never issue closesocket on s concurrently with another Winsock function call*. Your idea of switching between blocking and non-blocking modes seems great.

Comment: why you not want use only asynchronous I/O ?

Comment: @RbMm I don't want to use asynchronous I/O because I am working with an old project that already uses blocking sockets, and changing it to asynchronous would take a lot of time.

Comment: @Steve you don't need to change everything to non-blocking.  Just put the socket into non-blocking mode before calling `connect()`, then put it back to blocking mode after the connection is made.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, this is what I will do.

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN [connect page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **Note**  When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as **connect**, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another blocking Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing blocking Winsock call on the same thread will lead to undefined behavior, and must never be attempted by Winsock clients.

So if you want to cancel `connect` call, you must do it from another thread:

```
/* apc callback */
VOID CALLBACK apc( _In_ ULONG_PTR data)
{
    /* warning, some synchronization should be added here*/
    printf("connect canceled by APC\n");
}

/* second thread code */
DWORD WINAPI cancel_thread_function(void* main_thread_handle)
{       
    /* wait 500 ms*/
    Sleep(500);

    if (test_if_connect_is_still_pending())
    {
        /* cancel connect */
        QueueUserAPC(apc, (HANDLE)main_thread_handle, (ULONG_PTR) NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}



/* The thread in which is executed the connect call */
HANDLE mainThread;
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &mainThread, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

/* create cancelation thread */
CreateThread(NULL, 0, cancel_thread_function, , 0, NULL);

/* Warning: I should close the handles... */

connect(...);
```

IMO, the EJP solution is the best (non-blocking `connect` and test with `select`).

Comment: The downside to the APC approach is that it has a race condition. After the thread deems `connect()` is still pending, `connect()` may exit and its calling thread moved on before the queued APC is actually seen, so it will stay in the queue and potentially interrupt something else in the future. So, after `connect()` exits, you would have to cancel the thread if it is still running, wait for it to actually terminate, and remove the APC from the queue if it is still in there.